# Can't read from File properly

Tags: c, file

I am trying to create a program where one can create an account using recommended information and can store it in a file.

Then there will be another function where it will print those information stored in file. Those information are taken input in `SignUp` function.

After saving those information in File, the .txt file information is weird(.txt file image is included).

When I try to call the function `Information()` to print the info stored before, either nothing print or some weird text got print instead.(Output image also included).

I hope I made my problem clear and someone can explain me where I made the mistake.

Necessary code given below. I created two function for `SignUP`(where it will take necessary info and store them in file), `SignIN` to verify my username & password. `Information()` function shows the the input taken from `SignUP` and print them.

[Output & the File.txt image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf11d.png)

```
struct information
{
char username[10];
char password[10];
int date, month, year;
int pnumber[20];
char fname[20];
char lname[20];
char fathname[20];
char mothname[20];
char address[50];

};

int main()
{
int i;
printf("1. SIGN IN\n2. SIGN UP\n");
printf("CHOOSE AN OPTION: ");
scanf("%d", &i);


switch(i)
{

case 1:
    signin();

case 2:
    signup();

}

mainmenu();

}

void info()
{
system("cls");
FILE* fp;
int choice, i;
fp = fopen("username.txt", "rb");
struct information u1;

if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("error in opening file");
}

        gotoxy(28, 2);
        printf("..........................");
        gotoxy(55, 6);
        printf("==== YOUR ACCOUNT INFO ====");
        gotoxy(55, 8);
        printf("***************************");
        gotoxy(55, 10);
        printf("NAME..%s %s", u1.fname, u1.lname);

        gotoxy(55, 12);
        printf("FATHER's NAME..%s %s", u1.fathname, u1.lname);

        gotoxy(55, 14);
        printf("MOTHER's NAME..%s", u1.mothname);

        gotoxy(55, 18);
        printf("MOBILE NUMBER..%d", u1.pnumber);

        gotoxy(55, 20);
        printf("DATE OF BIRTH.. %d-%d-%d", u1.date, u1.month, u1.year);

        gotoxy(55, 22);
        printf("ADDRESS..%s", u1.address);

    int choose;
    printf("WOULD YOU LIKE TO GO BACK TO MAIN MENU?:\n");
    printf("< 1 > YES\n");
    printf("< 2 > NO\n");
    scanf("%d", &choose);

    if (choose == 2)
    {
        menuExit();
    }
    else
        mainmenu();
}

void signup()
{
char password[20];
int passwordlength, i, seek = 0;
char ch;
FILE *fp, *fu;
struct information u1;
struct information p1;


// Opening file to
// write data of a user
fp = fopen("username.txt", "ab");

system("cls");
printf("\n\n!!!!!CREATE YOUR ACCOUNT!!!!!");

printf("\n\nFIRST NAME...");
scanf("%s", &u1.fname);

printf("\nLAST NAME...");
scanf("%s", &u1.lname);

printf("\nFATHER's NAME...");
scanf("%s", &u1.fathname);

printf("\nMOTHER's NAME...");
scanf("%s", &u1.mothname);

printf("\nADDRESS..");
scanf("%s", &u1.address);

printf("\nDATE OF BIRTH...");
printf("\nDATE-");
scanf("%d", &u1.date);
printf("\nMONTH-");
scanf("%d", &u1.month);
printf("\nYEAR-");
scanf("%d", &u1.year);

printf("\nPHONE NUMBER...");
scanf("%s", u1.pnumber);

printf("\nUSERNAME.. ");
scanf("%s", &u1.username);

printf("\nPASSWORD..");
scanf("&d", &u1.password);

// Taking password in the form of stars
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    ch = getch();
    if (ch != 13)
    {
        password[i] = ch;
        ch = '*';
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
    else
        break;
}

fwrite(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp);

fclose(fp);
printf("\n\nACCOUNT CREATED SUCCESSFULLY.\n");

char option[10];
printf("\nPRESS ANY KEY THEN ENTER TO GO TO SIGN IN PAGE");
scanf("%s", &option);
signin();
}

void signin()
{
system("cls");

char username[50];
char password[50];

int i, j, k;
char ch;
FILE *fp, *fu;
struct information u1;


// Opening file of
// user data
fp = fopen("username.txt","rb");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("\nERROR IN OPENING FILE\n");
    printf("FILE DOESN'T EXIST\nYOU HAVE TO CREATE AN ACCOUNT FIRST\n");
    printf("PRESS ANY KEY & ENTER TO CREATE AN ACCOUNT\n");
    char option[10];
    scanf("%s", &option);
    signup();
}
gotoxy(34, 2);
printf(" ACCOUNT LOGIN ");
gotoxy(7, 5);
printf("***********************************************"
       "********************************");

gotoxy(35, 10);
printf("==== LOG IN ====");

// Take input
gotoxy(35, 12);
printf("ENTER USERNAME.. ");
scanf("%s", &username);

gotoxy(35, 14);
printf("ENTER PASSWORD..");

// Input the password
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    ch = getch();
    if (ch != 13)
    {
        password[i] = ch;
        ch = '*';
        printf("%c", ch);
    }

    else
        break;
}

// Checking if username
// exists in the file or not
while (fread(&u1, sizeof(u1), 1, fp))
{
    if (strcmp(username, u1.username) == 0)
    {
        mainmenu();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\n\nINFORMATION INCORRECT. PRESS ANY KEY & ENTER TO TRY AGAIN\n");
        char option[10];
        scanf("%s", &option);
        signin();
    }

}


fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: First, you should correctly indent your code to increase its readability. I count 3 `fopen` and only 2 `fclose`, I'm not sure it's a good idea. Finally, you use `scanf` a lot, without controlling the returned value or the read values. First check that what you read is good before writting it to a file (a function named "`print_info`" should be useful). A good reading about `scanf`: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: "After saving those information in File, the .txt file information is weird" You are storing the whole struct in a binary file. Don't expect to get something that you can read in a text editor

Comment: The way you read password is wrong - for a number of reason - but the worst part is that you never zero terminate the string

Comment: In `sigin` you read a password but you don't use it. Strange.

Comment: The phone number `int pnumber[20];` is wrong. It should be a string, as requested by `scanf("%s", u1.pnumber);`

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are quite many bugs in your code and even more "bad practice" examples. Let's take a few.

```
scanf("%s", &u1.fname);
```

This is both wrong and dangerous.

1. `&` shall not be used since `fname` is a char array
2. `%s` without a size (width) specification is something that you **should never do**
3. The return value from `scanf` **shall always be checked**

So the code should be:

```
if (scanf("%19s", u1.fname) != 1)
{
    // Input error
    ... add error handling here...
}
```

Next:

```
scanf("&d", &u1.password);
```

Here you use `%d` which means "scan for an integer" but `password` is a char array. That's obviously a bug.

and

```
scanf("%s", u1.pnumber);
```

Here you use `%s` which means "scan for characters" but `pnumber` is an integer array. That's obviously a bug.

In the function `signin` you have code that reads a password. However, your code never ever uses the value that you read. Strange... probably a bug.

Also notice how your `password` variables have different sizes. Some times 10, some times 20, sometimes 50. And when it is 20, you still allow the user to input 50 chars. That's bad... very bad.

And there are plenty more.

That said I think your are mainly confused about:

> After saving those information in File, the .txt file information is weird

What you are doing is to write a whole `struct information` object to a binary file. This means that every single byte of the struct (and any padding it may have) will be written to the file as raw values. For instance `int pnumber[20];` will cause the file to contain 20 integers in whatever raw format your system is using.

Such binary files can't be opened in a text editor like notepad. You will just get all kinds of strange symbols.

So your expectation are wrong. Your `.txt` are not really text files and can't be read using simple test editors.

That doesn't mean that the file is wrong. The may be fine but opening it in a text editor makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I can understand some of my clumsy mistake now. But, can you explain to me what's wrong with Information() and why it's now showing the information correctly? And how can I fixed it?

Comment: You here. Still having the same problem in Information() @4386427